# angular 8 populate drop down from observable

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and trying to populate a dropdown from an observable in Angular 8 but getting no joy.
I can see the webs service is getting data as I write it to the console log but somehow is not getting displayed on the page.

I've searched the net high an wide to no avail.  Any help is appreciated

error I get is:
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

**fetchdata.components.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FetchdataService } from '../fetchdata.service';
import { ServiceTypes } from '../models/servicetypes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetchdata.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {

  serviceTypes: ServiceTypes[];
  serviceType: ServiceTypes;
  isLoaded = false;

 constructor(private _testService: FetchdataService) { }

 getServiceTypes(): void {
   this._testService.getServiceTypes().subscribe(data => {
     if(data) {
       this.serviceTypes = data;
       this.isLoaded = true;
       console.log('List of Service Types', this.serviceTypes);
     }
   } );
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   // fetch all the service types
   this.getServiceTypes();
   //this.serviceType = this.serviceTypes;
 }
}
```

**fetchdata.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ServiceTypes } from './models/servicetypes';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FetchdataService {

  public testURL = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dfxy8';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getServiceTypes(): Observable<ServiceTypes[]> {
    return this._http.get<ServiceTypes[]>(this.testURL);
    }
  }
```

**serviceTypes.ts**

```
export interface ServiceTypes {
    Code:string;
    Description:string;
    VolumetricRatio: string
}
```

**fetchdata.component.html**

```
<p>fetchdata works!</p>


<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>



<select>
<option *ngFor="let serviceType of serviceTypes" [value]="serviceType.code">{{serviceTypes.Description}}</option>
</select>


<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let serviceType of serviceTypes">
      {{ serviceType.Code }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**console log**
[console log showing data and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbZU0.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Sounds like you're trying to iteratore over an Object instead of an Array. You say you print the data to console log? What does the data look like?

Comment: That's because you are getting an object instead of an array as response.

Comment: Hi Carsten, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, you're getting object instead of array in API response. You need to assign the target array to your variable.

**Code:**

```
this._testService.getServiceTypes().subscribe(data => {
     if(data) {
       this.serviceTypes = data.ServiceType; // <----- notice .ServiceType
       this.isLoaded = true;
       console.log('List of Service Types', this.serviceTypes);
     }
});
```

You should also create a new `interface` file for response `json` and use that in your service method. Something like:

```
export interface ServiceTypeApiModel {
    ServiceType: ServiceTypes[];
}
```

And then in your `service` method, cast the response into this model like:

```
getServiceTypes(): Observable<ServiceTypeApiModel> {
  return this._http.get<ServiceTypeApiModel>(this.testURL);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Robw you can use async filter that omits to call subscribe function

```
serviceType: Observable<any>;

getServiceTypes(): void {
   this.serviceType = this._testService.getServiceTypes();
}
```

in the view HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let serviceType of serviceTypes.ServiceType | async">
      {{ serviceType.Code }}
</li>
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: thanks a bunch for all the answers.  Its now finally working after days of pain with Syed's answer .  I will test all other solutions too