# Populate dropdown from observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I try to fill an array with values provinding from one service.

The array must fill a dropdown. I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480320/angular-8-populate-drop-down-from-observable).

The array is defined like this :
`dropdownList: Array<{id: number, description: string}>;`

The service method's is :

```js
async loadFoodTypes(){
    const api: string =  environment.apiAddress + 'FoodType';
    await this.httpClient.get<FoodType[]>(api)
    .pipe()
    .toPromise()
    .then((response: FoodType[]) => {
      this._foodType.next(response);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

The FoodType type is defined like this:

```js
 id?: number;
    description: string;
    shortDescription: string;
```

When I call the service I try to fill array with data.

```js
loadFoodTypes(){
    this.foodtypesService.loadFoodTypes().then(response => 
      this.dropdownList.push({id: <number>(<unknown>response as FoodType).id, description: (<unknown>response as FoodType).description})
    );
  }
```

My problem is that I have these 2 error messages in the browser console :

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

and

`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`

I presume the second one is linked to the first one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning anything from loadFoodTypes(). That's why

```
this.foodtypesService.loadFoodTypes().then(response =>
```

isn't working. Your response is undefined.

The way that's "more Angular" would be something like

- In the service:

```js
loadFoodTypes(): void {
    const api: string =  environment.apiAddress + 'FoodType';
    this.httpClient.get<FoodType[]>(api)
    .subscribe(response => this._foodType.next(response))
  } 

...

getFoodTypes(): Observable<FoodType[]> {
   return this._foodType.asObservable();
}
```

- In the component:

```js
loadFoodTypes(){
    this.foodtypesService.getFoodTypes()
        .subscribe(foodTypes => 
         this.dropdownList = foodTypes.map((foodType: FoodType) => ({id: foodType.id, description: foodType.description})
        );
  }
```

And don't forget to unsubscribe from your observables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't return the data in the load food type function,

```
async loadFoodTypes(){
    const api: string =  environment.apiAddress + 'FoodType';
    await this.httpClient.get<FoodType[]>(api)
    .pipe()
    .toPromise()
    .then((response: FoodType[]) => {
      this._foodType.next(response);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Also, the code in the catch don't rethrow the error so it will return `undefined` in the next `.then`

---

General notes on your code:

1. You can remove the `.pipe` as it
2. Don't use `.toPromise` as it deprecated

Comment: You mean I need to return response like this?
`
async loadFoodTypesResponse(){
    const api: string =  environment.apiAddress + 'FoodType';
    await this.httpClient.get<FoodType[]>(api)
    .subscribe((response: FoodType[]) => {
      return response
    })
} 
`

Comment: No, returning from the subscribe function will do nothing, you can keep using promises or use the PizzaBoy answer for more Angular way.

Comment: I haven't error message anymore but my dropdownlist is always not populated. I try to fill it like this `this.foodtypesService.getFoodTypes()
        .subscribe(foodTypes => this.dropdownList.push({id: <number>(<unknown>foodTypes as FoodType).id, description: (<unknown>foodTypes as FoodType).description}));` but I think it's wrong.

Comment: Have you try pizzaboy answer?

Comment: Yes I did but foodTypes type is different to dropdownlist type. So I try to fill dropdownlist with data they needs. FoodType is an Array. Need I to return the same type, you think? This is more difficult.

Comment: Try creating reproduction example and add the link so I'll have better understanding and I could help you more

Comment: It's difficulat to reproduce example on stackBlitz because it's part of a big project. At the moment I try to map response like this : 'this.foodtypesService.getFoodTypes()
        .subscribe(foodTypes => this.dropdownList = foodTypes.map(food => {food.id, food.description}));' but now the is on dropdownList and says "can't assign void[] type to '{ id: number; description: string; }[]'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238431/discussion-between-raz-luvaton-and-paintbox).